# Comparing two dates has an error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have code that is checking the trigger entry and seeing if the currently entered date is earlier than a date specified.

So it goes something like this

`if (trigger.new[0].EffectiveDate__c < foo[0].foo__c)
    trigger.new[0].EffectiveDate__c.addError('Error on Trigger');`

Simple enough, but whenever the `triggers.new` Date is 01/31/2014 , and the `foo` is set to 02/20/2014 it passes as true, even though 1/31 is infact earlier than 2/20.

Is there a better function to do a comparison

Comment: Are both EffectiveDate__c and foo__c fields of type Date not text? By the way, 01/31/2014 < 02/20/2014 is true and should result in your "Error on Trigger".

Comment: Are both values in the same time zone? Have you used `system.debug` statements to see what the values being compared actually contain?